# Nexus proxy to Artifactory virtual repository

Tags: maven, nexus, artifactory

I have Nexus as local repository manager and have a couple of proxied repositories to remote repositories managed by Artifactory. Everything works fine except when the remote repository is a virtual one. In that case nexus can't find .index at the remote repo. And indeed no such folder exists when browsing the virtual repo. Is there any way to get nexus to manage a local cache of a Artifactory managed virtual repo?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Artifactory doesn't publish an index in the standard maven form iirc. However this index isn't required for Nexus to do it's job, it's only needed to search the contents of the remote repository. This won't affect the ability to proxy artifacts.

Comment: Okey. Thanks, then I know that that's no issue. Will try to sort it out on Monday.